# volley timeout error...Data inserting two times

Tags: java, android, database, android-volley

I m getting `volley timeout error` every time i try  to insert data..Despite of the error, the data is inserted correctly but its inserting two times every time i press the `button`.
I need to remove the `error` and insert data only once. Also it takes too much time after clicking `button` to display error.

```
package com.example.sumit.myapplication;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.widget.CardView;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.MutableData;
import com.google.firebase.database.Transaction;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

/**
* Created by Sumit on 20-02-2018.
*/

public class register extends Fragment{
RequestQueue requestQueue;
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,                     Bundle savedInstanceState){
    getActivity().setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.login,container,false);
    return v;
}
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstancesState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstancesState);
    TextView t = (TextView) ((MainActivity) getActivity()).findViewById(R.id.textView3);
    t.setText("Register");

}


@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    final View vt = super.getView();
    final CardView b=(CardView)vt.findViewById(R.id.cardView);
    final TextView txt = (TextView)vt.findViewById(R.id.uid);
    final EditText txt1 = (EditText) vt.findViewById(R.id.editText);
    final EditText txt2 = (EditText) vt.findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    final EditText txt3 = (EditText) vt.findViewById(R.id.editText3);
    final EditText txt4 = (EditText) vt.findViewById(R.id.editText4);
    final Spinner hostel1=(Spinner) vt.findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    final Spinner branch1=(Spinner) vt.findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
    final String HttpUrl = "https://testzineapp.000webhostapp.com/insert_record.php";




    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View vt) {

            final String id=txt1.getText().toString().trim();
            final String name=txt2.getText().toString().trim();
            final String number=txt3.getText().toString().trim();
            final String email=txt4.getText().toString().trim();
            final String hostel=hostel1.getSelectedItem().toString().trim();
            final String branch=branch1.getSelectedItem().toString().trim();

            StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, HttpUrl,
                    new Response.Listener<String>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(String ServerResponse) {

                            // Showing response message coming from server.
                            Toast.makeText(getContext(), ServerResponse, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    },
                    new Response.ErrorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {

                            // Showing error message if something goes wrong.
                            Toast.makeText(getContext(), volleyError.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }) {
                @Override
                protected Map<String, String> getParams() {

                    // Creating Map String Params.
                    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    // Adding All values to Params.
                    params.put("College_ID", id);
                    params.put("Name", name);
                    params.put("Mobile_Number", number);
                    params.put("Email_ID", email);
                    params.put("Hosteller", hostel);
                    params.put("Branch", branch);

                    return params;
                }

            };

            // Creating RequestQueue.
            RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext());

            // Adding the StringRequest object into requestQueue.
            requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
            txt1.setText("");
            txt2.setText("");
            txt3.setText("");
            txt4.setText("");


};
    });
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because of volley default retry policy your your request is processing two times, try this code to avoid it.

```
stringRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(20 * 1000, 0, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));

        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(_context);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
```

Comment: Thank you so much...It resolves the two times saving problem...But still the data is inserted successfully sometime and sometime i got the error...and the time taken in displaying error/response is too long

Comment: Okay..I also think it is a server side error as it is accepting the values now correctly without any error. ..I hav 1 more question, i want to have data from my database to print on the activity. I want to have ID of that registered user after adding data of that user